# Angular2 loading compoents dynamically fails

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to load components duynamically in my view and this is what i have tried

in my html file

```
<p>
 <dynamic-component [componentData]="componentData"></dynamic-component>
</p>
```

Then in my ts file i have

```
export class ChatCmpComponent implements OnInit {
 private componentData = null;

 ngOnInit() {
  this.componentData  = {
    component: ChatInitButtonComponent,
  };
}
```

Now am getting an error

```
Can't bind to 'componentData' since it isn't a known property of 'dynamic-
component'.

1. If 'dynamic-component' is an Angular component and it has 
'componentData' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

What could be wrong, how do i dynamically load components

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `ng-template` and create a custom directive that will allow you to inject your component via a reference to a `ViewContainerRef`

for more information and an example, try here:

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader